# не работает код на питоне

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if i != j:
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                del a[j]
```

выдает ошибку:

```
if a[i] == a[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

почему так? если поставить вместо `del` - `print`, то все работает
?????????????

Comment: Потому что вы удаляете элемент из массива и, тем самым, делаете массив короче, что не соответствует изначальному len(a), заданному в range, что на последующих итерациях приводит к выходу за пределы массива. Лучше не удалять элемент, а заполнять какой-нибудь заведомой ерундой-заглушкой, например None, либо создать и заполнять новый массив, либо не использовать цикл for, а, например, while с постоянной проверкой выхода за пределы массива. Да, либо воспользоваться Set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такую задачку можно решить удаляя элементы с конца

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1]

for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    for j in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
        if i != j:
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                del a[j]
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

Потому что при удалении элемента списка изменяется количество элементов в нем и соответственно длина. Изначально ты передаешь len(a) в качестве аргумента для функции range(), который не изменится пока не закочинтся цикл.
С учетом того что оригинальный список "уменьшается" наступает момент когда значение j(от 0 до 7), превышает новую длину списка a.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1] #len(a) =8

for i in range(len(a)):# range(8) до конца цикла
    for j in range(len(a)):# range(8) до конца цикла
        if i != j:
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                del a[j] #здесь len(a) -1
```

Например

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
j =7
a[j]
```

Вызовет:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: спасибо, помогло